# Linking GSL to C via make

Tags: c, makefile, gsl

Umpteenth linking question. I am trying to build some simple C code that calls the GNU scientific library. However, the GSL folder is not nested in my project folder. So, the code lives in, say, `C:/c-examples/` and the GSL library is `C:/gsl`.

This is the C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl_math.h>
#include <fit/gsl_fit.h>

     int
     main (void)
     {
       int i, n = 4;
       double x[4] = { 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000 };
       double y[4] = {   12,   11,   14,   13 };
       double w[4] = {  0.1,  0.2,  0.3,  0.4 };

       double c0, c1, cov00, cov01, cov11, chisq;

       gsl_fit_wlinear (x, 1, w, 1, y, 1, n,
                        &c0, &c1, &cov00, &cov01, &cov11,
                        &chisq);

       printf ("# best fit: Y = %g + %g X\n", c0, c1);
       printf ("# covariance matrix:\n");
       printf ("# [ %g, %g\n#   %g, %g]\n",
               cov00, cov01, cov01, cov11);
       printf ("# chisq = %g\n", chisq);

       for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
         printf ("data: %g %g %g\n",
                        x[i], y[i], 1/sqrt(w[i]));

       printf ("\n");

       for (i = -30; i < 130; i++)
         {
           double xf = x[0] + (i/100.0) * (x[n-1] - x[0]);
           double yf, yf_err;

           gsl_fit_linear_est (xf,
                               c0, c1,
                               cov00, cov01, cov11,
                               &yf, &yf_err);

           printf ("fit: %g %g\n", xf, yf);
           printf ("hi : %g %g\n", xf, yf + yf_err);
           printf ("lo : %g %g\n", xf, yf - yf_err);
         }
       return 
}
```

And here is the makefile I wrote for it:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -IC:/gsl -lgsl
OLSexample: OLSexample.o 

clean:
    rm -f OLSexample OLSexample.o
```

However, running `make` on this exits with error 2, file not found. I think I might be doing something wrong in the makefile specifying the dependencies, or in linking the libraries. Any help is welcome.

---

**EDIT2:**

Following mux's advice, and the template [here](http://mrbook.org/tutorials/make/Makefile-4) I changed the makefile to the following (including the full paths to the library). I continue to get the previous error (e=2).

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -IE:/programming/c/libraries/gsl-1.15.tar/gsl-1.15/
LDFLAGS= -LE:/programming/c/libraries/gsl-1.15.tar/gsl-1.15/
LIBS= -lgsl
SOURCES=OLSexample.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=OLSexample

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The complete error message is included here for reference:

```
e:\programming\c\WorkingFolder\gslExamples\1-ols>make
make
gcc -c -Wall -IE:/programming/c/libraries/gsl-1.15.tar/gsl-1.15/   -c -o OLSexample.o OLSexample.c
process_begin: CreateProcess((null), gcc -c -Wall -IE:/programming/c/libraries/gsl-1.15.tar/gsl-1.15/ -c -o OLSexample.o OLSexample.c, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [OLSexample.o] Error 2
```

Comment: I think that has something to do with tabs and indentation check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7783920/gnu-make-yields-commands-commence-before-first-target-error

Comment: Right, so I figured that was the case, and removed all \t and \n. Now I am back to square one. There is something about this linking process that I am just not getting.

Comment: First, that's not the complete Makefile, you're missing the last bit, second, now that you use LDFLAGS when linking the object files you should add any linker flags to a variable called LDFLAGS and also the Libraries should go after the $(OBJECTS)

Comment: I have updated my makefile to take into account your latest suggestion. Will you be able to confirm that you are able to compile this example?

Comment: I think you should try and see if it works

Comment: I did indeed. It didn't work for me (identical error message), so I am wondering if I am linking to the wrong GSL directory (I am linking to the absolute top level, not to any include directory). I am also worried about the include directives in my code, which I have updated in the main question now.

Comment: looks like OLSexample.c is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured out what the problem is. Turns out that I had another version of `make` as discussed [on this thread](http://www.allegro.cc/forums/thread/593750).

Answer (score 4):

You should add `-LC:/gsl` to the list of searched directories , `-I` adds an include directory to be searched for headers, and `-L` adds a directory to be searched for libraries with `-l<lib>`. However, I don't see you actually compiling anything, maybe you should start with a Makefile template instead:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -Ic:/gsl
LDFLAGS= -Lc:/gsl
LIBS= -lgsl
SOURCES=main.c
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Ok, so I was using the wrong switch `-I` instead of `-L`. Thanks for the correction. I still get the e=2 error -- The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Mux, I have added to the question following your suggestions. I continue to get the same error -- could you take a look?

Comment: Why have you added `-c` to CFLAGS? This flag should be used when compiling `.c` to `.o` file without linking and not for every compilation. Further, it's typically better to not define rules for this translation but use the built in rules.

Comment: That's exactly why it's there, multiple files are compiled separately and then linked once, I don't see the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Your latest error indicates that GNU make is having trouble running a command.  In windows, it uses the CreateProcess function, and that function is failing.  This has nothing to do with gsl anymore.  Is gcc on your path?  What do you get if you just type gcc instead of make?

Comment: Thanks David. I am using MinGW on 64-bit Windows, and the path to the bin is in my global path variable:
e:\programming\c\WorkingFolder\gslExamples\1-ols>gcc
gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

Comment: Furthermore:
e:\programming\c\WorkingFolder\gslExamples\1-ols>gcc -Wall OLSexample.c
gcc -Wall OLSexample.c
OLSexample.c:2:22: fatal error: gsl_math.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.