# ld: library not found for -lgsl

Tags: macos, path, gsl

I'm working in OSX and I'm attempting to run a make file and when I try I get the following:

```
ld: library not found for -lgsl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [harm] Error 1
```

Earlier I found out the I needed to get the gsl library and I used mac ports and typed:

```
sudo port install gsl
```

into my command line window and it seemed to isntall okay. Is the missing lgsl not configured correctly or does it not come with gsl? I tried googling lgsl but didn't get much. I've only been at programming a few days and I don't know if I was supposed to set a path, or even really how to do that.

Thanks for any help you guys could offer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I just wanted to say that I had the exact problem on OSX. Rather than setting an environment variable, I used an additional compiler flag `-L/opt/local/lib`, which then lets one use `-lgsl`. I reference [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12968399/1358677) answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Anyone else still having this problem?
EDIT: This post helped: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28441755/unable-to-link-gsl-library-in-mac-os-x

Comment: @hlin117 have you tried `\`gsl-config --libs\`` when linking?

Answer (score 22):

I got the same issue and here is how I fixed it:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/lib/
```

I had previously installed gsl using:

```
brew install gsl
```

Comment: what is the difference between `LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on mac? when to use them?

Comment: and where is it documented? How did you know about that?

Comment: Chevdor thanks for sharing this, got my inkscape build moving along a little further.

FWIW, `/usr/local/Cellar` is symlinked to `/usr/local/opt` i find using `/usr/local/opt` to be a little less brittle for use cases such as this.

thanks again

Comment: My homebrew `Cellar` folder was under `/opt/homebrew`, not under `/usr/local/`.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is for dynamic linking whereas `LIBRARY_PATH` is for static linking. Your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will contain `*.dylib` files (dynamic link libraries) and your `LIBRARY_PATH` will contain `*.a` files (static libraries). Often, (but not always) the path where the dylibs and static libs are stored are the same.

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the path for where the macports installed the gsl library to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable (or most likely into the build script environment).  I believe macports stores things in /opt/local/lib

Comment: When I type echo $PATHS I get the following: 

    /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/texbin

Which does show that /opt/local/lib is in my paths. I've never heard of LD_LIBRARY_PATH, and it is not set when I echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATHS, so I set it with export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/local/lib", but that still does not resolve the issue. I am not doing something right still?

Comment: Minor update: I do not know what LD_LIBRARY_PATH is exactly, but I corrected the path for LIBRARY_PATH to /opt/local/lib, and got things to run smoothly.