# Where is the documentation of c lang env variables?

Tags: linker, clang, bundle

**TLDR** I tried to read the clang llvm documentation to find a way to pass library path, I wasn't successful. Then I searched and found a solution. I am curious where I can find the documentation of my solution.

**Details and why**

I was trying to run ruby's bundle on my catalina and I faced this error:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
```

I reinstalled openssl using `brew install openssl` and then `brew link openssl` I received the follwoing response from it:

```
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"

For pkg-config to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/pkgconfig"
```

While I appreciated brew's effort to make it work non of those worked. I narrowed the linker issue to this to see what's going on:

```
clang -dynamic -bundle -o asdf  -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypt -v
```

Finally [using `LIBRARY_PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35144610/1358124) I made passed the enviornment variable

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were able to make the `clang` linkage:

```
clang -dynamic -bundle -o asdf  -L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.19/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypt -v
```

succeed when it otherwise failed by setting:

```
export LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib/
```

in the environment of the `clang` command.

That's evidence that `clang` is influenced by the `LIBRARY_PATH` environment
variable in the same way as GCC compilers.

`LIBRARY_PATH` is not mentioned in the `ENVIRONMENT` section of [`man clang`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html),
or indeed at all, so this GCC-like behaviour can strictly be viewed as not mandatory.
It seems likely however that the omission is an oversight in the manual,
since `clang` generally strives to be an unobtrusive substitute for `gcc`. If
we run a Linux `clang` linkage in verbose mode:

```
$ export LIBRARY_PATH=/wheres/wally; clang -v main.o -L. -lfoo -lbar 
clang version 10.0.0-4ubuntu1 
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
Candidate multilib: .;@m64
Selected multilib: .;@m64
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --build-id --eh-frame-hdr \
 -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out \
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o \
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o \
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtbegin.o \
 -L. -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9 \
 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu \
 -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../.. \
 -L/usr/lib/llvm-10/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib \
 -L/wheres/wally \              # < There's wally!
 main.o -lfoo -lbar -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc \
 --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed \
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/crtend.o \
 /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

we observe `clang` inserting the expansion of `-L${LIBRARY_PATH}` into
the `ld` commandline after all of the other `-Ldir` options. And if we
track down [`LIBRARY_PATH` in the `clang` source tree](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/f0acfaf9241899552eca6baf3db1cebd1d6f2034/clang/lib/Driver/ToolChains/CommonArgs.cpp#L264-L267),
we'll see the code that makes it do so.

In the `ENVIRONMENT` section of [`man gcc`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc),
`LIBRARY_PATH` is documented:

> LIBRARY_PATH

> The value of LIBRARY_PATH is a colon-separated list of directories, much like PATH .
> When configured as a native compiler, GCC tries the directories thus specified when
> searching for special linker files, if it can't find them using GCC_EXEC_PREFIX .
> **Linking using GCC also uses these directories when searching for ordinary libraries
> for the -l option (but directories specified with -L come first).**

and the same appears verbatim in [GCC online documentation: 3.21 Environment Variables Affecting GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html)

What `clang` does with `LIBRARY_PATH` conforms with the sentence I've emphasised.

It's worth knowing that while using `LIBRARY_PATH` for this purpose may have got
you out of a jam, it is not favoured in regular linkage practice, because it is
likely to be an invisible hand when you are studying the output of a
linkage: its effect is only revealed in verbose mode (by either `gcc` or `clang`). The
installer's recommendation:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
```

is what you'd expect. I've no insight into why it didn't work for you.

Comment: `LIBRARY_PATH in the clang source tree` link broken