# How do I fix "ld: library not found for -lubsan" while compiling with g++?

Tags: gcc, macos-big-sur, sanitizer

When I try to compile my `eek.cpp` file with `g++ eek.cpp -o eek -fsanitize=undefined` flag, it shows:

```
ld: library not found for -lubsan
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but `g++ eek.cpp -o eek` is working fine.
[My terminal screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpHD2.png)

I'm using zsh and gcc 10.2.0 on macOS Big Sur. `fsanitize=undefined` was still working yesterday before I updated my macOS from Catalina.

The `ubsan.h` file does exist in `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/10.2.0_2/lib/gcc/10/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin20/10.2.0/plugin/include`, but it isn't working.
I've also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16682156/ld-library-not-found-for-lgsl) but it didn't solve my problem. How should I fix it?

Comment: *How* are you building? Please [edit] your question to show us the exact commands. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Obviously you need the ubsan *library*, not the ubsan *header*.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem since I updated my macOS, but have just now fixed with `brew upgrade`.
I'm sorry that I can't say what formula was involved in this problem, but updating formulae would be worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when trying to compile a fortran program and getting the error `ld: librarynot found for -lSystem`. The answer of @kaage helped me but I don't have enough reputation to comment it.

I just wanted to add that when running `brew upgrade` it complained that my command line tools were too outdated. Running (as suggested by brew itself)

```
 sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
 sudo xcode-select --intsall
```

fixed it.

Not sure this perfectly targets the question asked though so feel free to correct me.