# Compiling with Cmake and using a header only library

Tags: c++, cmake, eigen, eigen3

The question is a continuation/repeated one to a previous question, which didn't resolve the issue i'm running into.

[Using Eigen with Cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267104/using-eigen-lib-in-my-cmake-project)

Compiling Eigen with make file is one step task. But in Cmake, how do you add a header only library (basically i am using only the Eigen folder from the extracted archive folder in the Eigen website, and disregarding the rest.) 
Note: Eigen folder has its own CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem today when I wanted to use the [stb_image.h](https://github.com/nothings/stb/blob/master/stb_image.h) library. I solved it this way:

Define the library with the header as input file:

```
add_library(stb_image SHARED stb_image.h)
```

As the file does not have a recognized file ending, you have to tell cmake which language the file is in (in this case, C):

```
set_target_properties(stb_image PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE C)
```

Finally, stb_image needs me to define `STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION` to enable compilation of the library:

```
target_compile_definitions(stb_image PRIVATE STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FindEigen3.cmake. Put it into `cmake/Modules` folder and add the following lines to your CmakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

You can find FindEigen3.cmake in the source of the Eigen library in `cmake/FindEigen3.cmake`

https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/971445a0e8ec311b4b663242b1f0ac668a9753ca/cmake/FindEigen3.cmake?at=default