# Eigen cmake requires "target_link_libraries" even though it's template-only

Tags: cmake, eigen

In Eigen library's [official cmake doc](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCMakeGuide.html), it requires the line `target_link_libraries (example Eigen3::Eigen)`. I have tried removing that line, but then the compilation would fail with "Eigen not found".

This directly contradicts the discussion in another StackOverflow question: [Using Eigen Lib in my Cmake project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267104/using-eigen-lib-in-my-cmake-project)

I don't understand why Eigen would need `target_link_libraries` even though it's a template-only library? Just like the above StackOverflow question, I'd assume I only have to include the Eigen headers (`include_directories()`) and it should work out of the box. It doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah now I know what's going on: there's a concept called "interface library" in CMake that doesn't actually build a library binary. It is designed precisely for template-only libraries like Eigen.

References:
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html#interface-libraries
- http://mariobadr.com/creating-a-header-only-library-with-cmake.html

Hope this helps other souls struggling with cmake!