# How does Eigen work as a header-only library?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Recently I am using Eigen library for a project. I’m curious why there’s no binary file to link, but only a header. I don’t really understand how Eigen works behind the scene to make this possible.

Comment: Read the source code - it's all in the headers

Comment: @UnholySheep Right, I just found out. But why is it still necessary to link Eigen library when working with CMake?

Comment: CMake linking is not the exact same as linking a precompiled library. Eigen provides a "library target" for CMake which you are linking, but this does not mean you are linking to a binary

Comment: @UnholySheep Really appreciate your explanation! I also found a related thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51887180/7299097 . I am now reading to learn more about the mechanism.

Comment: Not sure what your question is actually about. Header-only libraries generally "work" by having every function `inline` (explicitly or implicitly). If this is about how this affects building with CMake, state that in your question more clearly (ideally showing a problem which you have).